# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in Firebug

Tags: php, jquery, debugging, firebug

I am getting the following syntax error from firebug:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
 $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
    type: "POST",
    url: "display.php",
    data:{faculties:faculty},            
    dataType: "json",   //expect json to be returned                
    success: function(response)
    {                    

        $.each(response,function(i,item)
        {
            $("table tbody").append("<tr><td>"+response[i].code+"</td>"+"<td>"+response[i].title"</td>"+"<td>"+response[i].lecturer"</td"+"<td>"+response[i].description"</td></tr>"); 
            // The line above is giving me the 
            // syntax error , i cant figure out what's wrong                                
        }); 
    }
});
```

This is the JSON object being passed by the PHP script
          `$data[]=array("code"=>$code,"title"=>$title,"lecturer"=>$lecturer,"description"=>$description);`

I have spend 1 hour debugging but I can't find the syntax error. Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$("table tbody").append("<tr><td>"+response[i].code+"</td>"+"<td>"+response[i].title"</td>"+"<td>"+response[i].lecturer"</td"+"<td>"+response[i].description"</td></tr>");
```

With

```
$("table tbody").append("<tr><td>"+response[i].code+"</td>"+"<td>"+response[i].title+"</td>"+"<td>"+response[i].lecturer+"</td>"+"<td>"+response[i].description+"</td></tr>");
```

Your **concating** was wrong.Use a good editor to traceout.

Answer (score 2):

You are not closing your `td` tag.

```
"+response[i].lecturer+"</td"+"<td>"+
---------------------------^^------
```

**Replace Your code with below**

```
$("table tbody").append("<tr><td>"+
    response[i].code+
    "</td><td>"+
    response[i].title+
    "</td><td>"+
    response[i].lecturer+
    "</td><td>"+response[i].description+
    "</td></tr>"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please used this

replace this code

```
      $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
             type: "POST",
             url: "display.php",
             data: {
                   faculties: faculty
             },
            dataType: "json", //expect json to be returned                
            success: function (response) {

            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                          $("table tbody").append("<tr><td>" + response[i].code + "</td><td>" + response[i].title + "</td><td>" + response[i].lecturer + "</td><td>" + response[i].description + "</td></tr>");
                         //The line above is giving me the syntax error , i cant figure out whtas wrong


           });

           }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace This in your Code

```
$.each(response,function(i,item)
{
$("table tbody").append("<tr><td>"+response[i].code+"</td>"+"<td>"+response[i].title"</td>"+"<td>"+response[i].lecturer"</td>"+"<td>"+response[i].description"</td></tr>");
});
```